# Why do people use ‘should’ in “It’s funny you should say that”?

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs, subordinate-clauses, omissibility, should

I’m a bit astonished about this special use of *should*:

1. (It’s) funny you **should** say that.

What explanation is there for using *should* in that expression?

I think there would be no diﬀerence in sense if it were
rewritten without that *should*, as in:

2. Funny that you say that.

Is the second variant, the one without the *should* before *say*, also
used?

If this second variant without *should* **does** actually exist, then does
it always mean the same thing as the *should* version means or can the
hypothetical second variant ever mean something slightly diﬀerent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'Should' sometimes appear to carry the idea of 'happen by chance''.

*If you see Fred tomorrow, please give him my regards. / If you **should** see Fred tomorrow, please give him my regards.*

*It's odd/strange/interesting (that) you say that. / It's odd/strange/interesting (that) you  **should** say that.*

*It was odd/strange/interesting (that) you said that. / It was odd/strange/interesting (that) you  **should** say that / **should have said** that.*

The utterances with 'should' are more tentative than those without.

Comment: Thanks for the clear hint that the variant 2 (without should) can also be used, and I think there is no difference. In my view the variant 1 is an imitation of a very queer French subjunctive after adjectives that express a personal judgement/comment on a fact. A subjunctive that I consider historical ballast.

Answer (score 3):

[Lexico's definition of "should"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/should) says:

> Used in a clause with ‘that’ after a main clause describing feelings.
>
> - ‘it is astonishing that we should find violence here’
> - ‘It seems to me revealing that Mr Halley and Mr Gibbins should describe him as if he were one and knew what he was doing.’
> - ‘I am astonished that you should take exception to an obviously Platonic enthusiasm.’
> - ‘He was so anxious that she should like them and they her.’
> - ‘It is shocking that we should pay many times more for the care of criminals than we do for the care of children with special needs.’

I don't think there's any tentativeness to it, but usages besides "it's funny you should say that" sound a bit quaint to my American ear.

Answer (score 1):

If we con­sider, slightly more for­mally:

- It is sur­pris­ing that you should say that.

And then start sub­sti­tut­ing *sur­pris­ing* with other ad­jec­tives,
then it seems more nat­u­ral, such as for ex­am­ple:

- It is in­cred­i­ble that you should say that.

I be­lieve that *should* here is a modal aux­il­iary ex­press­ing
a sub­junc­tive mood, al­though oth­ers may dis­agree.

Comment: Logically it is difficult to understand this use of should, but I know this use. I consider this manner of expression as a kind of quirk. And even grammars have difficulty to show the logic of this "should". I would like to know whether English speakers would use variant 1 or both variants.

Comment: @rogermue: It may be easier if you think about the word *happen* being elided:  "It's funny you should *happen* to say that."

Comment: I don't think that the subjunctive mood can be blamed on the French: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_subjunctive#Old_English_subjunctive

Comment: I only speak of the use of should in sentences of the type It's funny (or similar adjectives expressing a judgement + that-clause). And here English should corresponds obviously to a subjunctive in French.

Comment: It would have been a subjunctive mood in old English, prior to any French influence. Modern english has almost abandoned the use of the subjunctive, though.